# Anyone happen to know what font this is?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification

[image]Wondering the name of this font, or the next closest thing to it. Image is from the StudioCanal trailer for the re-release of the movie. I've tried What The Font and FontSquirrel without much luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characters "e" shows that this is not a font but a handwritten logo. You can make an advanced search at myfont.com with: `lettering` + `brush` + `marker` + `handwritten` to find some similar fonts

[image]

Or try to make it yourself with a Photoshop brush:

[image]

<sub>Source: [creativemarket.com](https://creativemarket.com/majkol/375758-90-Sharpie-Marker-Brushes-for-PS)</sub>

Comment: Agreed. And all three "l"s are different as well. Definitely not a font.